# How to REALLY disable emoji for symbols

Tags: html, wordpress, hex, symbols, emoji

I would like to use a regular [symbol](https://coolsymbol.com) (the up-right-arrow) in a Wordpress menu. I copied the symbol character into the required field and it looks good on desktop. For some reason, the iPhone I use displays an emoji instead of the character. I already activated the Wordpress plugin "Disable Emojis" but this doesn't help. How do I force smartphones to display the simple black arrow instead of a colored arrow emoji?

The usual searches just bring up the idea with the Wordpress plugin which probably disables emojis globally but still lets smartphones override that.

[Screenshots (Imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cTdb.jpg)

Comment: This should really work: `↗`

Answer (score 0):

You will never get the same emoji / symbol depending on os, service, browser, app, etc ... because it is interpreted.

Find below some examples :

1. On Twitter
 
[image: On twitter]

 2. On FaceBook
 
[image: On facebook]

 3. On Instagram
 
[image: On instagram]

 4. On WordPress wysiwyg as text content
 
[image: Wysiwyg as text content]

 5. On WordPress wysiwyg as visual content
 
[image: Wysiwyg as visual content]

Comment: So when I am unable to use other methods other than symbols (such as the img tag or css background and and svg) I am basically f*ed?

Comment: Kind so, yes! There is no other choice to keep constency than using SVG, or image.

Answer (score 0):

For the text variant, use the text presentation sequence:

```
U+2197 U+FE0E (↗︎)
```

For the emoji variant, use the emoji presentation sequence:

```
U+2197 U+FE0F (↗️)
```

For the default variant, use only the character:

```
U+2197 (↗)
```

but, as already mentioned, how will it be displayed by default depends on many factors: OS, browser, etc.

See: [Emoji Presentation Sequences, v11.0](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-variants.html)

Comment: So when I am unable to use other methods other than symbols (such as the img tag  or css background and and svg) I am basically f*ed?